# Реализация нестандартной таблицы умножения

Tags: c, таблицы, умножение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, с написанием кода на `С`, должно выглядеть как на картинке
Написала код на С++, но на С не знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С чем именно у вас возникли трудности? Где ваши наработки?

Comment: Что тут нестандартного и с чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Так как с языком С я не очень знакома смогла написать код на С++, но мне нужно сдать задание на С. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
std::cout <<"x|  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 " << std::endl;
std::cout <<"-------------------------------------" << std::endl;
for ( int x=1; x<= 9; x++){
    std::cout.width(6);
    for(int y=1; y<=9; y++){
        if(y<x){
            std::cout.width(4); std::cout<<std::right<<"";
        }
        else{
            if(y<10){
                std::cout.width(4); std::cout<<std::right<<x*y;
            }
        else{
            std::cout.width(6); std::cout<<std::right <<x*y;
        }
        }
    }
 std::cout<<std::endl;
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде слишком много лишнего, можно выбросить целое условие.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  puts("x| 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ");
  puts("-------------------------------------");
  for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
      if (y < x) {
        printf("    ");
      } else {
        printf("%4d", x*y);
      }
    }
    puts("");
  }
}
```

хотя если вопрос в том, что бы **именно так как на картинке**, тогда вот так

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  puts("  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 ");
  puts("--------multiplication table----");
  for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
      if (y < x) {
        printf("   ");
      } else {
        printf("%3d", x*y);
      }
    }
    puts("");
    puts("------------------------------");
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: О, анонимный минусатор отошел от праздников!

Answer (score 0):

Просто замените функции вывода...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    puts("x| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ");
    puts("-------------------------------------");

    for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++)
        {
            if (y < x)
            {
                printf("    ");
            }
            else
            {
                if (y < 10)
                {
                    printf("%4d",x*y);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%6d",x*y);
                }
            }
        }

        puts("");
    }
}
```